# Styling list items with different colors

Tags: html, css

I'd like to style my list items with three different colors. What is the recommended way of doing that?

My code so far:

```css
li { 
  width: 33.333%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  list-style: none;
}

.light {
  background-color: #085dce;
}

.medium {
  background-color: #0051bb;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #004bad;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>light-color</li>
  <li>medium-color</li>
  <li>dark-color</li>
  <li>light-color</li>
  <li>medium-color</li>
  <li>dark-color</li>
  <li>light-color</li>
  <li>medium-color</li>
  <li>dark-color</li>
  <li>light-color</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `nth-child` to differ items.

```
li:nth-child(3n+1) {background-color: #085dce;}
li:nth-child(3n+2) {background-color: #0051bb;}
li:nth-child(3n) {background-color:#004bad;}
```